# How to get list of url and use in scrapy python for web data extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, woocommerce, scrapy

I am creating web scraper using scrapy python. Here is my code

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = [
    'https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/',
]

    def parse(self, response):

            yield {
                    'product_link': response.css('a.product-image-link::attr("href")').get(),
                    'product_title': response.css('h3.product-title>a::text').get(),
                    'product_price': response.css('span.price > span > bdi::text').get(),

                }
            next_page = response.css('ul.page-numbers>li>a.next.page-numbers::attr("href")').get()

            if next_page is not None:
                print()
                print(next_page)
                print()
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
        'title': response.css('h1::text').get(),
        'batt': response.css('td.woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value p::text')[3].get(),
        'brand': response.css('div.woodmart-product-brand img::attr(alt)').get(),
        'brandimg': response.css('div.woodmart-product-brand img::attr(src)').get(),        
        'price': response.css('p.price').xpath('./span/bdi/text()').get(),
        'r-price': response.css('p.price').xpath('./del/span/bdi/text()').get(),
        's-sale': response.css('p.price').xpath('./ins/span/bdi/text()').get(),
        'breadcrumbs': response.css('nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb a::text').getall(),
        'tags': response.css('span.tagged_as a::text').getall(),
        'attributes': response.css('td.woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value p::text').getall(),
        'img': response.css('figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__image a::attr("href")').getall(),
        'description': response.css('div.woocommerce-product-details__short-description p::text').get(),
        'description1': response.css('#tab-description > div > div > p::text').getall(),
        'description2': response.css('#tab-description > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > p::text').getall()
        }
```

It's a woocommerce website.
There are total of 57 pages and 12 products per page.
Total of 684 products estimated.

But my code returns nothing.

What I did wrong while scraping the URLs ?

Answer (score 1):

To extract the all page information you need to extract the next page url and then parse the url.

Here is a simple example, I think that help you to sort out the issue.

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = [
    'https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/',
]

    def parse(self, response):

            yield {
                    'product_link': response.css('a.product-image-link::attr("href")').get(),
                    'product_title': response.css('h3.product-title>a::text').get(),
                    'product_price': response.css('span.price > span > bdi::text').get(),

                }
            next_page = response.css('ul.page-numbers>li>a.next.page-numbers::attr("href")').get()

            if next_page is not None:
                print()
                print(next_page)
                print()
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page)
```

Comment: sir what will be my full code, actually i need to extract data from every url means single product page

Comment: You could extract the every product url from the all page then go through every product url to collect the required data.

Comment: Sir i have updated the code in question with your code but it returns nothing in csv. Can you please tell me where i done mistake

Comment: You should remove second parse method. this is not the way that you extract the data.

Comment: Sir i run your code in scrapy and it only deliver the data of only first product in every page. There are 12 products per page and it only return data of first item of per page.

Comment: Yes, It was an example how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this should do it:

```
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css(".product-grid-item"):
            yield {
                'product_link': item.css('a.product-image-link::attr("href")').get(),
                'product_title': item.css('h3.product-title > a::text').get(),
                'product_price': item.css('span.price > span > bdi::text').get(),
            }
        next_page = response.css('a.next:contains(→)::attr("href")').get()

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.